# How to put Count so that it won't have warning

Tags: ios, arrays, directory, warnings

I would want to put a count instead of long however it does not work this is my code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *locations = @[ @"Bottoms", @"Dress", @"Coats", @"Others", @"hats", @"Tops" ];
NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:locations];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
collectionTrash.delegate =self;
collectionTrash.dataSource=self;
for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
    NSLog(@"i");
    NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
    if(data)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [allImagesArray addObject:image];
        NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);
    }}
for(NSString *folder in locations) {

    // get the folder contents

    for(NSString *file in directoryContent) {

        // load the image

    }
}}
```

I am getting an error at the locations in the fpath line. It is saying that incompatable pointer types sending NSArray strong to parameter of NSString.  How can I get rid of this warning? With reaserch I have done something wrong with length.  What should I do to get everything rolling? This is the compiler warning

```
2013-08-25 16:21:28.890 [1899:907] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to 

    instance 0x1d5458c0
    2013-08-25 16:21:28.893 [1899:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d5458c0'  
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x32c8b2a3 0x3a96f97f 0x32c8ee07 0x32c8d531 0x32be4f68 0x334fc8c9 0x89ee7 0x34ab2595 0x34b3e353 0x34b7fd11 0x34b7efe7 0x34ca13ef 0x34b7e0c5 0x34b7e077 0x34b7e055 0x34b7d90b 0x34b7de01 0x34aa65f1 0x34a93801 0x34a9311b 0x3679a5a3 0x3679a1d3 0x32c60173 0x32c60117 0x32c5ef99 0x32bd1ebd 0x32bd1d49 0x367992eb 0x34ae7301 0x89c35 0x3ada6b20)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
    (lldb)
```

Feel Free to ask if you want to see more of the code

Comment: Please stop asking the same question with the same code. How did yesterday's answers not help. Update the original question.

Comment: Seriously. You have been asking the same questions over and over again, on different accounts, for weeks. Stop! Focus on making one question comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code instead of line 4.

```
NSString *fPath = documentsDirectory;
for(NSString *component in locations)
{
    fPath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:component];
}
```

Comment: This answer seems correct to me, I don't know why it was downvoted other than the fact that it might be able to be made more efficient (not really relevant...)

Comment: This will at least fix the crash. Although, `fPath` will probably always only point to the last element of `locations`.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Why?  It appends every single one (reassigned to fPath)

Comment: Ug, yeah - wasn't reading close enough sorry. Although I'm pretty sure from the other questions, each directory in `locations` is a sibling directory, so this would probably form a non-existent path.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I was going back and forth on that one myself...couldn't decide.  Although going by the flow of the last duplicate I think you might be right.